# Angular appends to router-outlet instead of replacing content

Tags: javascript, angular

Am learning Angular, When I use the routerLink or this.router.navigate the component is simply appending to router-outlet instead of replacing the content. This is my code

**app-routing-module**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'Billing', component: BillingComponent},
  {path: 'BillDisplay', component: BillDisplayComponent}
];
```

**app.component.module.html**

```js
<a routerLink="/Billing">
    Go to Billing
</a>
<router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

when I click on the link on the rendered page, I get the billing page with screwed up Jquery, but I try giving the same URL directly in the browser, http://localhost:4200/billing, the page displays fine. Also, I have a button on billing,

**billing.component.html**

```js
<input type="button" (click)="navigateTo()" value="Submit">
```

**billing.component.ts**

```js
navigateTo(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/BillDisplay']);
  }
```

now when I click on the button, the content of `billdisplay` displays in the same page appended to billing like below.

```
contents of app.component.html
contents of billing.component.html
contents of billdisplay.html
```

Why is the navigation not replacing the contents?

Comment: Can you please provide images? It will help understand the problem a lot better.

Comment: Post Billing Display Html and code please

Comment: Post more code , not clear what you are asking.
Html and js of your component and your routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This one

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() =>{
          this.router.navigate(['/BillDisplay']);
        })
```